# Save symfony form entity type into a new entity as a reference

Tags: php, forms, symfony

### What I am doing

I'm generating a form dynamically from 3 entities (form/element/option) that contain elements of the form and if applicable options (think checkboxes/dropdown boxes).

Symfony forms are designed that you setup the fields to match an entities, which when instantiating, populate the form with the values of that entity.

I however want the entity populating the form to be that of the users submission entity but the form to be constructed from the form entity. So I have added functionality to a custom form, it builds itself from the form entity, but then expect a submission entity.

```
$formClass = new FormType();
$formClass->setDataModel($formEntity);
$this->createForm($formClass, $submission, array());
```

### What is/isn't working

I'm able to render a checklist element, the values are pulled from 'form element option' entity, however I wish to save the user selection to a 'submission element option' entity.

For each choice they make (each 'form element option' selected), i want a 'submission element option' saved.

The checklist element's options are from the FormElementOption entity,  but the user submissions will be SubmissionElementOption (which references the FormElementOption).

I am transforming the entities using the transformer at the bottom of this question, however when a submission doesn't previously exist - it tries to set its parent `$subOption->setSubmissionElement($this->element);` but can't.

In the form `$form->getData()` (would be the entity if previously saved) is null, this is passed to the transformer as `$this->element`.
Being null, the new submission option cannot have its parent set and thus ends in an error that the options `setSubmissionElement` cannot be null.

---

From the form creation view you have:

```
[Form] hasMany [Element] hasMany [Option]
```

Form:

```
id  |  name
1   |  'form 1'
```

Element:

```
id  |  name  |  form_id  |  type
1   |  'a'   |  1        |  'checklist'
2   |  'b'   |  1        |  'checklist'
3   |  'c'   |  1        |  'text'
```

Option:

```
id  |  name    |  element_id
1   |  'a'     |  1
2   |  'b'     |  1
3   |  'c'     |  1
4   |  'd'     |  1
5   |  'a'     |  2
```

---

From the form submissions you have:

```
[Submission] hasMany [SubmissionElement] hasMany [SubmissionElementOption]
```

Submission:

```
id  |  user_id  |  form_id
1   |  1        |  1
```

Submission element:

```
id  |  submission_id  |  element_id
1   |  1              |  1
```

And finally Submission element option:

```
id  | submission_element_id  |  option_id
1   | 1                      |  1
2   | 1                      |  2
3   | 1                      |  4
```

---

The form is built using data from the FormElement entity, which when saved should return a FormSubmissionElement entity.  so I set the class here:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => '\AppBundle\Entity\FormSubmissionElement'
            ));
    }
```

To render the elements of the form, I pass the constructor the FormElement.
FormChoiceType is a simple type that extends EntityType and passes the element to the data Transformer.

The form renders the element in a pre_post_data event listener:

```
$form = $event->getForm();
/** @var \AppBundle\Entity\FormSubmissionElement $data */
$data = $event->getData();
...

$submission_options = $data !== null ? $data->getOptions() : null;
$submission_element = $data;
$type = new FormChoiceType($submission_element, $submission_options);
$form->add($element_name, $type, array(
    'by_reference' => false,
    'class' => 'AppBundle:FormElementOption',
    'label' => $element->getLabel(),
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => $element->getMultiOptions(),
    'choice_label' => 'label',
    'mapped' => true,
    'disabled' => $disable_all || $element->isDisabled() ? true : false
));
```

OptionTransformer:

```
    public function __construct($element, $options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;
        $this->element = $element;
    }

    public function transform($options)
    {
        $data = array();

        if($options !== null) {
            foreach($options as $opt) {
                // TODO: Replace this with em->getReference vs EAGER FETCH ON ENTITY
                $data[] = $opt->getOption();
            }
        }


        return $data;
    }  

    public function reverseTransform($options)
    {
        $new = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach($options as $option) {
            $added = false;
            if($this->options !== null) {
                foreach ($this->options as $opt) {

                    // sub exists
                    if ($opt->getOption() != null && $opt->getOption()->getId() == $option->getId()) {
                        $new->add($opt);
                        $added = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!$added) {
                $subOption = new FormSubmissionElementOption();
                $subOption->setOption($option);
                $subOption->setSubmissionElement($this->element);
                $new->add($subOption);
            }
        }
        if($this->element !== null && $this->element->getOptions() !== null) {
            foreach($this->element->getOptions() as $opt) {
                if(!$new->contains($opt)) {
                    $this->element->getOptions()->removeElement($opt);
                }
            }
        }


        return $new;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote and no comment, super helpful

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your question is and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried rewriting the initially explanation as best I can.  Hopefully that will help better understand the question.

Comment: Old question but if I understood it correctly you are trying to have the form schema in the database. For that you need this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

 If you want to find ready made code you should probably search for projects that uses json schema. http://json-schema.org